# Trying to send the value of a radio button in a form to a php variable.

Tags: php, forms, variables, radio-button

I tried the following code, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I know I'm breaking rules by having the form spread out amongst two different divs, but I don't know any other way around it.

```
<?php
echo '<form name="form" method="POST">';
$directory = '/var/www/admin/html/content';
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));
echo 'Files<br>';
while($it->valid()) {
    if(!$it->isDot()) {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="file_picked" value="content/' . $it->getSubPathName() . ' " id="file_picked" />' . $it->getSubPathName() . '</br>';
    }
    $it->next();
}

echo '<input type="submit" name="pickedName" value="Edit File" /></div>
<div class="editor">
<h1>SS Code Editor</h1>';

$file_picked = $_POST['file_picked'];
$edit_field  = $_POST['edit_field'];

if(isset($_POST['pickedName'])) {
    //get file contents and display in textarea box
    $theData = file_get_contents($file_picked);
    echo "<textarea name=\"edit_field\" id=\"edit_field\" cols=\"100\" rows=\"60\">";
    echo $theData;
    echo "</textarea><br />";
}

if(isset($_POST['submitChanges'])) {
    //grab new textarea contents and put into file.
    $theData = file_put_contents($file_picked, $edit_field);

    //redraw textarea with new contents
    $theData = file_get_contents($file_picked);
    echo "<textarea name=\"edit_field\" id=\"edit_field\" cols=\"100\" rows=\"60\">";
    echo $theData;
    echo "</textarea><br />";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submitChanges" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space at the end of the checkbox input value :

Replace :

`value="content/' . $it->getSubPathName() . ' " id="...`

with :

`value="content/' . $it->getSubPathName() . '" id="...`

So file_get_contents($file_picked = $_POST['file_picked'])) don't find any file (with space at the end) and returns false, which is displayed as "" in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Your value should be stored in $_POST['file_picked']